# gitlab-runner using directory path instead of URL to clone; fails with "does not appear to be a git repository"

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to run my GitLab CI tests locally, to speed up developing CI.

I installed `gitlab-runner` locally (on my GNU/Linux box) following [these instructions](http://campfirecode.io/debugging-gitlab-ci-pipelines/).

Now, when I run `sudo gitlab-runner exec docker test`, I get:

```
sudo gitlab-runner exec docker test
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=7133 revision=0e5417a3 version=12.0.1
Running with gitlab-runner 12.0.1 (0e5417a3)
Using Docker executor with image joyzoursky/python-chromedriver:2.7 ...
Pulling docker image joyzoursky/python-chromedriver:2.7 ...
Using docker image sha256:f593ebe67d0c75eb8e3d663412c8fc80df70bd08e835d7a64ba6afa21b1c2d8a for joyzoursky/python-chromedriver:2.7 ...
Running on runner--project-0-concurrent-0 via hostname...
Fetching changes...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/project-0/.git/
Created fresh repository.
fatal: '/home/USER/path/to/repo' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
FATAL: exit code 1
```

(`/home/USER/path/to/repo` is the actual path to my working directory containing `.gitlab-ci.yml`, and my project code)

So, it looks like `gitlab-runner` is trying to use the directory path as a git clone URL, which obviously won't work.

I tried specifying `--clone-url=`, but I can't understand what part of the full project URL (either in the main git repo, or the gitlab mirror) I should be using.

Any clues?

Comment: Is `/home/USER/path/to/repo/` a git repo?

Comment: It is, yes! But my guess is that the Docker image can't access the repo via that path, because it only exists on my workstation, not in the docker image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Fedora and have SELinux enabled; try setting that to permissive:

```sh
sudo setenforce 0
```

SELinux blocks any activity that isn't allowed by some existing policy. The GitLab runner is basically a docker container trying to access files on the host machine, so that gets blocked...which leads the runner to report that you don't have a valid repository at  (an error saying it can't read the files would have made more sense but we don't live in a perfect world)

The lazy fix is to make SELinux blanket permit the activity, if you don't do this sort of thing often enough to warrant a policy change for example.

The more security conscious will prefer to edit the policy instead. Figure out some unique identifier in the denial error, then create a new policy to allow it

```sh
sudo grep <needle> /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M gitlab
sudo semodule -i gitlab.pp
```

Comment: Just as well this was an answer because it answered the question  Maybe I should turn SELinux alerts back on 

Comment: Could we get a bit more explanation on *why* this works?